# JqGrid & Grails EasyGrid plugin: How do I replace [object Object] in grid?

Tags: java, grails, jqgrid, grid, tostring

I have a "Customer" class with a one-to-many relationship with a class called "Representative". On the client-side I see the cells for "representative" in the grid are set to "[object Object]". I would like that cell to contain the "toString()" value of the "Representative" class.

[image: object Object]

What changes do I need to make to my grid definition so that those cells contain the "toString()" value of the "Representative" class?

Note: Since there can be many "representatives" associated with a customer, I only need the data of the first representative returned.

This is how the grid is defined in my Controller:

```
    //Customer Grid
    def customerGrid = {
        domainClass Customer
        columns
        {
            customer_id
            customer_name
            representative          
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and updated how I defined my grid in my Controller.
I was able to access those properties by defining my grid like so:

```
 //Customer Grid
    def customerGrid = {
        domainClass Customer
        columns
        {
            customer_id
            customer_name
            representative
            'representative.firstName'
            {
                name 'Sales Rep Name'
            }          
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps someone else. It was hard to find such a specific answer since this only applies to an EasyGrid implementation of jqGrid inside of a Grails (Java) Framework application.